# Web Analytics Web Part displaying multiple copies of same document in Top Content List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-analytics

I have added and configured a Web Analytics Web Part in our SP 2010 environment.  The web part is used to display the 10 most frequently viewed documents in the site collection.  However, it appears to be doubling up on the documents.  So if I opened one document 3 times it shows it being opened up 3 times twice.  Has anyone seen this before and know of the cause?  Is it just because it is brand new and hasn't accumulated a lot of information yet?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I have posted a pic to illustrate what I mean here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbE4k.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found this post still lurking here unanswered and realized after some time, I can now answer my question and maybe help someone else who notices the same thing.  This "problem" was entirely due to low stats to report on.  We have now been running the web part in production for a few weeks with a lot more documentation and traffic to report on and the data looks fine in the web part.  So if someone else runs into this and questions the data returned, lack of data to report on will be the culprit.